# Bluej asks for reference when I try to add Graphics

Tags: java, graphics, bluej

This might be a very dumb question but I tried to solve this for hours and am really tired, so I just found out about about Graphics and I wanted to draw a rectangle in bluej but in every tutorial it asks me to do this (Graphics g) and bluej asks me to add a reference for this but In the tutorials it doesnt. A huge thank you in advance for anyone who helps me.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class test extends JFrame
{  
    public test()
    {
       JFrame frame=new JFrame();
       frame.setSize(640, 480);
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(100,100,200,200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the entire error and point out where in the code it's being marked as an error.

Comment: You're extending `JFrame` and creating a second `JFrame`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: there is no error that is marked. The problem is that Bluej asks me to put a reference in the constructor for Graphics g when I run the paint method. This does not happen in any tutorial I've seen and I dont know how to fix it

Comment: Thank you Gilber Le Blanc. It works now. I dont really know how it makes a difference whether you create a new JFrame or use the extend but it solved it.